# How to serve user generated levels?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

What is the easiest way to store online and serve user-generated levels? What client-server architecture should I use? Will I need backend code, or just a database? What database would be the easiest to use with C++ front-end? Are there any suitable cloud services that would help to minimize the effort?

I am looking for something that can be used on both mobile and desktop.

The game we're going to make will be fairly simple, the levels can fit into one screen, each level is basically collection of integer coordinates of cubes of different types. Any tips on how and where to store such levels?

Comment: As your question is currently written it is hard to tell what you are actually asking about. Do you ask about the network protocol? A file format for your maps? Or about a client/server architecture? Please try to be more specific about where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Still unclear. Have you tried writing a TCP server and storing each level in a file? That's like 20 lines in most programming languages, tops.

Comment: I haven't tried that, can you point me on an article about how to setup a TCP server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will definitely need a proper server backend. Allowing your end-user client to access your database directly would be very dangerous, because databases systems usually do not support permission settings which are fine-grained enough to allow users to create, update and delete their own data but not the data of other users. Also you will definitely want some kind of plausibility check to make sure that user-submitted levels do at least fulfill the minimum requirements to be playable. That would be far too complex for most database systems.

Which database would be "the easiest one to use with C++ front-end" is very subjective, because it depends on how exactly you intend to use it. You could go with a classic SQL database or with one of the many, very different NoSQL solutions. The options for providers which offer different databases as a service are also plentiful, and they differ a lot in price and in the scale and quality of service. Which database to use and where to host it is a decision which depends on your personal requirements and preferences, so we can not help you to make it.